# Is my proof for $(A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C)$ only when $C \subseteq A$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was working through the Chapter 3 supplementary exercises in Grimaldi's textbook, and I wanted to see if my way of answering a problem is correct.  The exercise asks you to prove $(A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C)$ if and only if $C \subseteq A$.  The book answer has a rather involved proof, but in my mind it's rather simple.  I'm fairly positive that I'm missing something, though, so I wanted to share my proof for others' thoughts.

Beginning with $(A \cap B) \cup C$, by the distributive law we get $(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$.  Now, if $(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C) = A \cap (B \cup C)$, that can only be true when $A \cup C = A$.  Otherwise, the intersection of $A \cup C$ and $B \cup C$ would include any elements in $C$ but not in $A$, which means the intersection of $(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$ would necessarily have more elements (because it would include other elements in $C$) than what is in $A \cap (B \cup C)$ alone. Therefore, for those two intersections to be equal, $A \cup C = A$.  And if $A \cup C = A$, then by definition $C \subseteq A$.  Thus, we're done.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: I think using a venn diagram would be more obvious. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram

Comment: Let  $X =(A\cap B)\cup C$ and $Y=A\cap (B\cup C).$ Then $X\supseteq C$ so $C=C\cap X.$  And $Y\subseteq A.$  So if $X=Y$ then $C=C\cap X=C\cap Y\subseteq Y \subseteq A.$ On the other hand if $C\subseteq A$ then $A\cap C=C,$ implying  $Y=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)=(A\cap B)\cup (C)=X.$

Comment: In my comment above, the idea for proving $X=Y\implies C\subseteq A$ came from asking "What happens when we intersect $C$ with either $X$ or with $Y$?"

Comment: That's a way to approach the problem that I didn't consider.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the other direction: you need to also start by assuming $C\subseteq A$ and show that this implies $(A\ \cap\ B)\ \cup\ C=A\ \cap\ (B\ \cup\ C)$. Your half of the proof looks good, though, and similar reasoning will lead you from the alternative assumption back to your original assumption.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense.  Thanks!